# Tampermonkey cant delete an element

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Im using Tampermonkey with jQuery and i try to remove few facebook elements but as i try they just do nothing, i tried with few other elements with them worked but with those which i need to remove, i cant.

element which i tried to remove is Facebook Comments Plugin on game app. http://prntscr.com/ay28a0
i tried remove elements before that element, didnt workout either.

```
$('').remove(); // didnt work using this method.
```

Comment: fb comments live in an iframe, you cannot manipulate contents of an iframe from a different domain. You would have to remove the whole iframe

Comment: @PatrickEvans i tried to do that either, it didnt work out.

Comment: @rivor2 It should work if you have the right class/ID for the container. Have a look at this example I just made: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/yXSmzrMS

Comment: @blex i actually found problem, each facebook game has iframe on the begining of code and i didnt notice that till i checked it and thats why i couldnt edit anything in that place where i needed, and thanks guys for the help. :)